# AngularJS testing using Karma

Tags: node.js, testing, angularjs, npm, karma-runner

I am very new to AngularJS and trying to test a piece of functionality using Karma.
I installed node.js and when I open it and enter the following it doesn't do anything.

```
$ npm install -g karma
```

Please anyone can help me how can I achieve this.

Comment: Which operating system? How did you install node + npm? I doubt there will be no error.

Comment: And you didn't typed the command into the node.js repl?

Comment: Its Windows 7, i didn't get any error while installing. I typed the command $ npm install -g karma, but it does .....

Comment: do it without the $ just npm install -g karma

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue.  I believe I wrote a fairly complete blob post about how to Setup AngularJS, Angular Seed, Node.js and Karma.  This post describes how to install Karma on a windows computer using the command prompt.

http://bardevblog.wordpress.com/2013/07/28/setting-up-angularjs-angular-seed-node-js-and-karma/

On Windows, you can install Karma from the Command Prompt.  Do not install it from within Node.js.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Steps to install Karma
1.install nodejs from https://nodejs.org/download/ site appropriate for your system
2.open command prompt and traverse to your project path 'C:\project folder\'
3.type and run this in command prompt ->npm install karma --save-dev
4.type and run this in command prompt ->npm install -g karma-cli